# The server tag is not well formed for imageButton

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, servertag

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Image1" Width="50px" Height="50px" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "ImageHandler.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("Ifile")  %>' OnClientClick='<%#"javascript:window.open(' ImageHandler.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("Ifile")  "')"%>' />
```

Does anyone tell me what's wrong with this tag? I'm getting error on this tag.

Comment: You should be including a `"runat=server"` tag for an asp controls?

Comment: The above code segment has that attribute after height and width

Comment: ASPX Page:

`<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
        onclick="ImageButton1_Click" />`

Code Behind:

    `protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Page.aspx");
    }`

Comment: the event for the client click is already on the tag. I am trying to enlarge the selected image on click at client side

Comment: Refer it might help you: [Enlarge image on client click ASP](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwidyYL-0tzRAhUFro8KHcLGAcgQFggfMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.aspsnippets.com%2FArticles%2FImage-Gallery-in-ASPNet-with-enlarge-image-preview-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx&usg=AFQjCNEFSFZhAor3vj0sl07MrJgAI7CfUw&bvm=bv.145063293,d.c2I)

Comment: I tried it but its not working in my case so i was trying the alternative.
when i click the image the div doesnot show the enlarge image it just shows the loading icon and i cannot even click the close button. Need to direct direct back the page. Can u help for this?

Comment: Post the whole code code behind and aspx code both.

Comment: Is your file path correct? Check your file path if it is reachable or not.

Comment: Yes i did the same i pasted all the jquery, css, the divs bt still unable to load the enlarged form of image. A popup div appers with load icon.giff but not the enlarge form of actual image appears

Comment: I believe yes, the image is successfully loaded to gridview but not on popup div.
'code' OnClientClick="return LoadDiv(this.src);
is this correct?

Comment: Give it a try looks correct.

Comment: arghh!!! then what did i missed? the div just keep loading with  loader.gif file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use an apostrophe `'` inside the binding, use `&#39;`.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Image1" Width="50px" Height="50px" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "ImageHandler.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("Ifile") %>' OnClientClick='<%#"javascript:window.open(&#39;ImageHandler.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("Ifile") + "&#39;)" %>' />
```